# Change numpy.seterr defaults?

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to change my seterr *defaults* to be either all 'warn' or all 'ignore'.  This can be done interactively by doing `np.seterr(all='ignore')`.  Is there a way to make it a system default?  There is no `.numpyrc` as far as I can tell; is there some other configuration file where these defaults can be changed?

(I'm using numpy 1.6.1)

EDIT: The problem was not that numpy's default settings had changed, as I had incorrectly suspected, but that another code, `pymc`, was changing things that are normally `ignore` or `warn` to `raise`, causing all sorts of undesired and unexpected crashes.

Comment: Do you want to change the defaults for interactive sessions, scripts, or both?

Comment: Interactive most importantly, but both.

Comment: Today one of my test scripts failed with `FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in subtract` with no changes made to the code at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is no configuration file for this. You will have to call `np.seterr()` yourself.

Comment: When/why did the defaults change?  In previous versions of numpy (before 1.4?) I never got any errors from, e.g., dividing by zero (it would default to NaN).

Answer (score 1):

For the interactive session, you can use the [`$PYTHONSTARTUP`](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) environment variable to point to a file, and then all commands in that file will be executed before the interactive session starts.